# enum with value starting with numbers in xsd

Tags: xml, enums, xsd, jaxb

My requirement is to have a element in the XSD to be restricted to some numbers

```
<xs:element name="RequestType">
    <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="001"/>               
         <xs:enumeration value="002"/>
         <xs:enumeration value="003"/>
    </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:element>
```

I tried using binding xml also but that is also not working

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='RequestType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='001']">
   <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="Inquiry"/>
</jxb:bindings>
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='RequestType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='002']">
      <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="Confirmation"/>
</jxb:bindings>
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='RequestType']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='003']">
     <jxb:typesafeEnumMember name="Force Payment"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Can some one please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to resolve this by using  "In-line Customization of an Enumerated Type Using a Combined Mapping"

Below is the example

```
 <xs:element name="RequestType" type="Request"/>

 <xs:simpleType name="Request">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember value="1" name="Inquiry" />
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember value="2" name="Confirmation" />
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember value="3" name="Force_Payment" />
        </jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
      <xs:enumeration value="1" />
      <xs:enumeration value="2" />
      <xs:enumeration value="3" />
    </xs:restriction>
```

This will generate an enum Request

```
@XmlType(name = "Request")
```

@XmlEnum(Integer.class)
public enum Request {

```
@XmlEnumValue("1")
Inquiry(1),
@XmlEnumValue("2")
Confirmation(2),
@XmlEnumValue("3")
Force_Payment(3);
private final int value;

Request(int v) {
    value = v;
}

public int value() {
    return value;
}

public static Request fromValue(int v) {
    for (Request c: Request.values()) {
        if (c.value == v) {
            return c;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.valueOf(v));
}
```